# Match data from array to data from file?

Tags: awk, array, cut

I'm trying to match up the data from an array the lists the days of the week like this:

```
MONDAY
TUESDAY
WEDNESDAY
THURSDAY
FRIDAY
SATURDAY
SUNDAY
```

The files data reads like this:

```
Name1,Tuesday
Name2,Friday
Name3,Sunday
Name4,Wednesday
Name5,Thursday
Name6,Saturday
```

The output should be:

```
MONDAY 
TUESDAY Name1
WEDNESDAY Name4
THURSDAY Name5
FRIDAY Name2
SATURDAY Name6
SUNDAY Name3
```

I am able to cut the data by the comma into two. I was wondering if it's possible to match the data from the file to the data within the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If file1 has the days of the week and file2 has the days and names, then:

```
$ awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[toupper($2)]=$1;next} {print $1,a[$1]}' file2 file1
MONDAY 
TUESDAY Name1
WEDNESDAY Name4
THURSDAY Name5
FRIDAY Name2
SATURDAY Name6
```

#### How it works

- `-F,`

  Use a comma as the field separator.
- `FNR==NR{a[toupper($2)]=$1;next}`

  While we are reading through the first named file, file2, add an entry to associative array `a` with the key as the upper case version of the day and value as the name.  Then, skip the rest of the commands and jump to the `next` line.
- `print $1,a[$1]`

  If we get to here, we are working on the second file.  In that case, print the day and the name that we retrieve from associative array `a`.

Comment: If I were to add a corresponding set of data with phone numbers to that awk command, how would I go about it? For example: Name1,5551112222 Name2,5552223333 Name3,5554445555, etc.